# Как сделать, чтобы условие прошло по всему словарю?

Tags: python, python-3.x, файлы

Нужно, чтобы в текстовый файл вывело результат построчно для каждой пары в словаре (количество строк неизвестно).

```
    for k, v in cur_data_dict.items():
        with open(r'current_balance.txt', mode='w', encoding='utf-8') as cur_blnc:
            if k[0:2] == '0x':
                cur_blnc.write(str(cur_balance_1) + '\n')
            else:
                cur_blnc.write(str(cur_balance_2) + '\n')
```

Answer (score 2):

Поменяй местами первые две строки и не забудь поправить отступы.

Или можно поменять режим открытия файла на append ("a").

Comment: или на a+ чтобы создать в случае отсутствия

Comment: @alex да, верно.